# Debo contar las letras especificas de un texto java

Tags: java

Por ejemplo si pongo la palabra "*casa*", necesito que devuelva 2 (Porque hay 2 "a"), pero en mi programa solo cuenta una, si la palabra tiene 2 letras iguales.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
            
    String letra;
    letra=sc.nextLine();
    String entrada="";
    String salida= "<>";
    int contador=0;
    while(!entrada.equals(salida)){
        entrada=sc.next();
    
        if(entrada.contains(letra)){
            contador++;        
        }
        if (entrada.contains(letra)){
            contador++;
        }
        if(entrada.contains(salida)){
            break;    
        }
    }
    System.out.println(contador);
}
```

Comment: Adjunta tu codigo

Comment: Es eso no se porque si pongo casa solo cuenta una a

Comment: Sobra un if del entrada.contains(letra) porque estaba probando cosas

Answer (score 1):

Pasa que el método `contains()` te devuelve true si efectivamente la letra esta contenida en la palabra, y como pones `break`(freno) detienes el bucle cuando el método contains devuelve true,por lo tanto tu contador solo aumenta en 1 ,tu lógica de ser recorrer toda la palabra o cadena y evaluar si la letra buscada aparece 1 o mas veces comparando cada letra de la palabra o texto con la letra buscada, para ello un ciclo for resultaría de mejor uso para entenderlo

```
      char letra;
        String entrada="";
        int contador=0;

        while(!entrada.equals("<>")){
        System.out.println("Ingresa entrada");
        entrada=sc.nextLine();
        if(entrada.equals("<>")){break;}    
        System.out.println("Ingresa letra");
        letra=sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
        contador=0;
//gracias al metodo length() podes obtener el tamaño de la cadena  
        for(int i=0;i<entrada.length();i++){
//con el metodo charAt() podes obtener las letras que componen el texto uno a uno
//mediante la condicional evaluas si una letra del texto es igual a tu letra buscada
//de ser asi aumenta en 1 el contador            
          if(entrada.charAt(i)==letra){
            contador++;
          }
        }

         System.out.println(contador);
       }
```

Comment: Vale, pero tiene que seguir pidiendo entradas hasta que pongas la secuencia "<>"

Comment: De ahí el while y el break esta para que si encuentra los caracteres con los que tiene que acabar el programa se acaba

Comment: usa un while que se detenga cuando la entrada ingresada sea igual a <> no necesitas break

Comment: While(!entrada.equals(salida)) {  entrada=sc.nextLine() ; y el for dentro también pero ahí contaba mal. Justo ahora no te puedo pasar más Código pero cuando pueda lo paso, pero había ese while

Comment: No funciona bien, tienes que poder poner todas las entradas que quieras y cuando quieras acabar pones <> y tiene que poner cuantas letras que quieras hay en todas las frases o palabras

Comment: Si pones la secuencia en medio de un texto debería omitir lo que va despues. Pero no lo hace